# How to parse json without a defined stucture?

Tags: json, dictionary, go, parsing

I want to parse this JSON :

```
{
        "error": null,
        "id": "tutu",
        "result": {
                "param1": 559,
                "param2": "yo",
                "param3": {"tab":["a", "b"], "param4":"hello"},
 
        }
}
```

The problem is that I want a flexible solution if the JSON structure changes: I want to be able to access each field with a key system (like in Javascript) without knowing in advance the JSON structure:

```
fmt.Println(jsonObj["result"]["param3"]["tab"][1])
```

Is it possible to do it ?

Comment: I think you will soon find that the usefulness of this idea is very limited. For example, `jsonObj["result"]["param3"]["tab"][1]` is quite a specific expectation of a certain structure.

Comment: Indeed, as rustyx implied, if you don't know the structure, then how do you know `jsonObj["result"]["param3"]["tab"][1]` exists?

Comment: When you need to change one element in JSON structure (ie : during development), with basic method, you need to modify several lines of code... with my proposal, we modify only one line.
With Javascript, you can do it natively and it is very convenient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in your case unmarshall directly into `map[string]interface{}` to save an assertion.

```
    var jsonObj map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &jsonObj)
```

Second, remember to check the assertion

```
    result, ok := jsonObj["result"].(map[string]interface{})
    if !ok {
        panic("not json obj")
    }

    param3, ok := result["param3"].(map[string]interface{})
    if !ok {
        panic("not json obj")
    }

    tab, ok := param3["tab"].([]interface{})
    if !ok {
        panic("not json arr")
    }
```

Lastly, you can declare a new type and "hide" the assertions in its methods

```
type AnyObj map[string]interface{}

func (obj AnyObj) MustObject(name string) AnyObj {
    v, ok := obj[name].(map[string]interface{})
    if !ok {
        panic("not json obj")
    }
    return AnyObj(v)
}

func (obj AnyObj) MustArray(name string) []interface{} {
    v, ok := obj[name].([]interface{})
    if !ok {
        panic("not json arr")
    }
    return v
}
```

Then use like this:

```
func main() {
    var jsonObj AnyObj
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &jsonObj)
    if (err != nil) {
        panic(err);
    }

    tab := jsonObj.MustObject("result").MustObject("param3").MustArray("tab")

    fmt.Println(tab[1])    
}
```

check it here https://play.golang.org/p/ucdMZ0VEKcr

Comment: And How do get param4 value with  MustObject ?

jsonObj.MustObject("result").MustObject("param3").MustArray("param4 ")
=> make panic

Comment: @ipStack `param4` is a string; you must assert it to string. you can add a method `MustString` that does the assert with similar logic as other methods, or also more simple: `jsonObj.MustObject("result").MustObject("param3")["param4"].(string)`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, although the fact that you need to assert the types makes it a bit unwieldy:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    b := []byte(`
    {
        "error": null,
        "id": "tutu",
        "result": {
                "param1": 559,
                "param2": "yo",
                "param3": {"tab":["a", "b"], "param4": "hello"}
        }
    }
    `)

    var jsonObj interface{}

    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &jsonObj)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    msg := jsonObj.(map[string]interface{})
    result := msg["result"].(map[string]interface{})
    param3 := result["param3"].(map[string]interface{})
    tab := param3["tab"].([]interface{})

    fmt.Println(tab[1])
}
```

This prints

```
b
```

like you would expect.

Note that this program **will panic**: not just if the JSON fails to parse, but also if the JSON does not exactly match the program's expectations: missing keys, different types and so on.

The [Generic JSON with interface](https://go.dev/blog/json#generic-json-with-interface) section of the [JSON and Go](https://go.dev/blog/json) article on The Go Blog has an example of checking the actual type of the thing at runtime; as was suggested in the comments, it's easy to forget.

Answer (score 1):

this is mine used [fastjson](https://github.com/valyala/fastjson):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/valyala/fastjson"
)

type ParseValue struct {
    *fastjson.Value
}

func Parse(b []byte) (*ParseValue, error) {
    var p fastjson.Parser
    v, err := p.ParseBytes(b)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &ParseValue{v}, nil
}

func (p *ParseValue) GetString(keys ...string) string {
    return string(p.GetStringBytes(keys...))
}

func main() {
    b := []byte(`
    {
        "error": null,
        "id": "tutu",
        "result": {
                "param1": 559,
                "param2": "yo",
                "param3": {"tab":["a", "b"], "param4": "hello"}
        }
    }
    `)

    v, err := Parse(b)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    r := v.GetString("result", "param3", "tab", "1")
    fmt.Println(r)

    rr := v.GetUint("result", "param1")
    fmt.Println(rr)

    // output:
    // b
    // 559
}
```