# Extract value from an array in a Json

Tags: json, go, reflect

I'm trying to get "boots" value

My func main

```
varjson:=`{
  "identifier": "1",
  "name": "dumbname",
  "person": {
    "items": null,
    "inventory": [
      {
        "T-shirt": "black",
        "Backpack": {
          "BigPocket": {
            "spell": "healing",
            "boots": "speed",
            "shampoo": "Head & Shoulders"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "Pockets": null
  }
}`

var res map[string]interface{}

json.Unmarshal([]byte(varjson), &res)

test(res)
```

test function

```
    func test(t interface{}) {
      switch reflect.TypeOf(t).Kind() {
       case reflect.Slice:
        s := reflect.ValueOf(t)
    for i := 0; i < s.Len(); i++ {
        fmt.Println(s.Index(i))
        }
      }
    }
```

But when I compile I get nothing
If is there another way to get the "boot" value in the Json?

Comment: `map[string]interface{}` are [hell to navigate](https://play.golang.org/p/V02Xqcov1ga) - try online resources like [json-to-go](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) to find a middle-ground struct to `json.Unmarshal` to

Comment: Sure, now I'm working with Structs generated by the webpage
https://play.golang.org/p/I2gHwTUUeBM
Got this code but still don't know how to get boots value :/

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/FCRpak-z0-1

Comment: It may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69130150/16182150

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can use types, based on your comment (thankfully cause totally agree with colm, trying to reflect the structure is rough.

Once you have a type its super easy to navigate.

specifically `fmt.Println(res.Person.Inventory[0].Backpack.BigPocket.Boots)`
would net you the boots value. Bearing in mind that Inventory is a slice so you probably need to iterate over that, whereas here I have directly accessed it, which will be bad if Inventory is empty or there are other elements.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type AutoGenerated struct {
    Identifier string `json:"identifier"`
    Name       string `json:"name"`
    Person     struct {
        Items     interface{} `json:"items"`
        Inventory []struct {
            TShirt   string `json:"T-shirt"`
            Backpack struct {
                BigPocket struct {
                    Spell   string `json:"spell"`
                    Boots   string `json:"boots"`
                    Shampoo string `json:"shampoo"`
                } `json:"BigPocket"`
            } `json:"Backpack"`
        } `json:"inventory"`
        Pockets interface{} `json:"Pockets"`
    } `json:"person"`
}

func main() {
    varjson := `{
  "identifier": "1",
  "name": "dumbname",
  "person": {
    "items": null,
    "inventory": [
      {
        "T-shirt": "black",
        "Backpack": {
          "BigPocket": {
            "spell": "healing",
            "boots": "speed",
            "shampoo": "Head & Shoulders"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "Pockets": null
  }
}`

    var res AutoGenerated
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(varjson), &res)
    
    fmt.Println(res.Person.Inventory[0].Backpack.BigPocket.Boots)
}
```

In your original, whats wrong is your switch statement only covers a slice, but the initial object is a map. So your switch is not finding a match initially